# Kinect 2? or keep Kinect 1

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working in project using Kinect1 in ROS to extract the depth information.
My question is If you have any experience with the two version 1 and 2 and If you feel really the difference ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187693/kinect-2?-or-keep-kinect-1/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far there does not seem to exist a driver for v2 of Kinect. According to other posts, people using v2 are doing so "mapping" a Windows-installed Kinect2.

---

Originally posted by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) with karma: 255 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-24**:
oh really ? I can't use kinect 2 in ROS ? this is what you mean ?

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-07-24**:
as of now, YES

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-07-25**:
See my answer here: http://answers.ros.org/question/187283/using-a-xbox-one-kinect-on-a-turtlebot/?answer=187364#post-id-187364

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-25**:
oh really !
Bad news.

**Comment by [oogabooga](https://answers.ros.org/users/20648/oogabooga/) on 2014-10-31**:
Is this the case still? Or have things changed?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-11-19**:
I think there is sth changer:
http://www.ros.org/news/2014/09/microsoft-kinect-v2-driver-released.html
I'm not working on a project with kinect now this is why I'm not really up date

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now you can work with the Kinect v2 thanks to the [nodelet](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_kinect2) from Thiemo Wiedemeyer. The kinect v2 is by far better that the kinect v1. Better depth map pixel resolution, an infrared output that allows night vision, and better robustness against sunlight (not perfect, but if the objects of the scene reflect good the near infrared, you can obtain depth information even under sunlight). The tricky part of the Kinect v2 is to handle the high amount of output data (therefore USB 3.0); we have recorded bags at a rate of 2 GB per minute, and sometimes we had problems obtaining the depth data. It is definitely worth changing to the kinect v2.

---

Originally posted by [manolovaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/21970/manolovaza/) with karma: 66 on 2015-12-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5